# Filter rows based on from and to date

Tags: php, date

I want to filter the table rows based on **From & To Date**. Frontend is working :

[image]

But onclick "search" button, page will refresh , but its not filtering the rows....

**html**

```
<form name="frmSearch" method="post" action="">

<input id="post_at" name="search[post_at]"  value="<?php echo $post_at; ?>"  />
<input id="post_at_to_date" name="search[post_at_to_date]" value="<?php echo $post_at_to_date; ?>" />            
<input type="submit" name="go" value="Search" >


<table id="content-table">

<tr>
<th>order id</th>      
<th>date</th>   
</tr>

<?php
 if(!empty($orderrecords))
    {
      foreach($orderrecords as $k=>$v)
      {     
?>  

<tr>    
<td><?php echo $orderrecords[$k]["order_id"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $orderrecords[$k]["sent_date"]; ?></td>
</tr>

</table>

<?php
      }
    }
?>
</form>
```

**php**

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "");

    $post_at = "";
    $post_at_to_date = "";

    $queryCondition = "";
    if(!empty($_POST["search"]["post_at"])) {           
        $post_at = $_POST["search"]["post_at"];
        list($fid,$fim,$fiy) = explode("-",$post_at);

        $post_at_todate = date('Y-m-d');
        if(!empty($_POST["search"]["post_at_to_date"])) {
            $post_at_to_date = $_POST["search"]["post_at_to_date"];
            list($tid,$tim,$tiy) = explode("-",$_POST["search"]["post_at_to_date"]);
            $post_at_todate = "$tiy-$tim-$tid";
        }

        $queryCondition .= "WHERE sent_date BETWEEN '$fiy-$fim-$fid' AND '" . $post_at_todate . "'";
    }

    $sql4 = "SELECT * from do_order " . $queryCondition . " ORDER BY sent_date desc";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql4);
```

**script**

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
showOn: "button",
buttonImage: "datepicker.png",
buttonText: "Date Picker",
buttonImageOnly: true,
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'  
});
$(function() {
$("#post_at").datepicker();
$("#post_at_to_date").datepicker();
});
```

**var_dump code** :

```
var_dump($sql4);
var_dump($post_at); 
var_dump($post_at_to_date);
```

**var dump result** :

```
string(100) "SELECT * from do_order WHERE sent_date BETWEEN '2018-03-01' AND '2018-03-27' ORDER BY sent_date desc" 
string(10) "01-03-2018" 
string(10) "27-03-2018"
```

I am using mysqli , let me know if you need any other information....

Please help me to find solution, Thanks in advance....

Comment: r u using ajax for This usually  in your form tag refresh your page so if you want your to result without reloading page then use ajax

Comment: @NavnitMishra thanks for suggestion..... i am not using ajax, also i dont have any problem with refreshing page, can you please check code and and tell me what wrong in code ?

Comment: can you please check your date picker date format and stored value  date format As i seems the problem is with your date format please recheck

Comment: @NavnitMishra this is date picker format : `01-03-2018` & this is what i saved in database : `2018-03-22` , is those conflict ?

Comment: @NavnitMishra please tell me what changes i need to make it work ?

Comment: yes first you change your date format then match

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167340/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-navnit-mishra).